# how to adjust width of bokeh heatmap and remove white space around

Tags: python-3.x, bokeh, heatmap

I would like to change the width of the heatmap cell so that its dimensions are square (even). Ideally, the cells are small and square so that I can fit several heatmaps with just one column of data. I want to reproduce something like this:

[image: nice heatmap]

My current code makes one heatmap that is too wide and there is lots of white space, as well as a strange y position that cuts off the bottom cell. Not sure what's going on. Thanks.
[image: bokeh heatmap]

```
def genHeatMap():
colours = ['#67d33d',
 '#76d74f',
 '#84da5f',
 '#91de6e',
 '#9ce17b',
 '#a6e488',
 '#b1e795',
 '#bbeaa1',
 '#91de6e',
 '#9ce17b']
values = [1.0,
 0.17647058823529413,
 0.08021390374331551,
 0.04054054054054054,
 0.06,
 0.07894736842105263,
 0.07317073170731707,
 0.05813953488372093,
 0.1320754716981132,
 0.0]
y_labels=['103', '134', '140', '185', '235', '292', '299', '431', '566', '659']
y = list(range(10)) 
x = ['a'] * 10 
df = {'xs':x,'ys':y,'value':values,'colour':colours,'labels':y_labels}
p = figure(x_range='a',y_range=y_labels,plot_width=300,plot_height=300,
          tooltips = [('CSID', f'@labels-103'), ('Tanimoto', '@value')])
p.rect('xs', 'ys', width=1, height=1, source=df,color='colour', line_color="black")
p.toolbar.logo = None
p.min_border_bottom = 20
p.min_border_left = 0
p.min_border_right = 0
p.min_border_top = 0
p.xaxis.major_tick_line_color = None 
p.xaxis.minor_tick_line_color = None 
p.xaxis.major_label_text_font_size = '0pt'
return p
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `p.x_range.range_padding = 0`

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/ranges.html#bokeh.models.ranges.FactorRange.range_padding

Comment: hi thanks for that. I'm new to bokeh, didn't know about this. It cleared up the white space on the sides, but up top it still remains. Also, is it possible to control the width size of overall plot? I want to shrink it into a square so I can make a subplot figure of them

Comment: You can set `range_padding` on the `y_range` as well. Plot size is controlled by `plot_width` and `plot_height`. For reference many of these kinds of questions are answerable in the documentation: https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/styling.html

Comment: i tried `y_range.range_padding =0` and also tried different values, but the white space still remained at the top. I did try all those other commands  like `min_border_top` but it still remains. The positioning of the plot is offset too, where the firs trow is cut off; seems like its not about the white spacing but the positioning of the plot?